# Compile TeX (directly) into SVG using the command line

Tags: svg

Is there a way to directly compile TeX code into the SVG image format (rather than going the detour over TeX => PDF => SVG)?

I found this question:
[Convert LaTeX to SVG online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103282/convert-latex-to-svg-online)

But I don't want to do it online - it should be a command-line call.

Comment: Perhaps http://download.cnet.com/Free-PDF-to-SVG-Converter/3000-18497_4-76168803.html . Google may find other downloadable tools.

Comment: `inkscape --without-gui --file=input.pdf --export-plain-svg=output.svg` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10290006/2442087)

Comment: Yeah, I know these solutions. I'm currently using pdf2svg-0.2.2. But I was hoping for a direct tex-to-svg solution...

Comment: What is the problem with going via PDF? You can still write a Makefile or define an alias, which includes the final conversion to SVG.

Comment: ok, i'll elaborate a little: i compile the latex code from inside a servlet. the output is sent to the user as a svg figure in a web page. using tex=>pdf=>svg works in principle, but is more costly in terms of server resources than i assume a single step would be. also, sometimes pdflatex doesn't terminate. i'm looking into the reason for this, but was hoping to avoid the debugging by simply avoiding pdf.

Comment: Does `batchmode` help to avoid the termination problem? See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037927/run-pdflatex-quietly)

Comment: `pdflatex --interaction=batchmode --halt-on-error` should resolve the not terminating.

Comment: Related [conversion - How can I use TikZ to make standalone (SVG) graphics? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51757/how-can-i-use-tikz-to-make-standalone-svg-graphics)

Answer (score 12):

## `tex2svg`

The command `tex2svg` becomes available once [`mathjax-node-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjax-node-cli) in combination with [`node.js`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) is installed.

With (X)Ubuntu LTS, this requires only two installation steps:

```
$ sudo apt install nodejs npm
$ sudo npm install --global mathjax-node-cli
```

The command:

```
$ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mathjax-node-cli/bin/tex2svg '\sin^2{\theta} + \cos^2{\theta} = 1' > test.svg
```

will yield:

[image: tex2svg output, rasterised at 300 dpi]

**Note 1:** If `node` is used with NVM, the path may be different. The path can be found with:

```
$ type node
/usr/bin/node
```

**Note 2:** The generated SVG file renders properly inside a browser but [cannot be displayed using standard image tools](https://print-css.rocks/blog/blog_2016-10-05-integrating-mathjax.rst).

**Note 3:** Generating SVG from a TeX file can be done as follows:

```
$ cat YOURSOURCEFILE.tex | xargs -0 -t -I % /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mathjax-node-cli/bin/tex2svg '%' > YOURENDFILE.svg
```

Comment: You may need to use 
`sudo npm install --global mathjax-node-cli` and `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mathjax-node-cli/bin/tex2svg '\sin^2{\theta} + \cos^2{\theta} = 1' > test.svg` now

Comment: this did not work for me: `npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {`

Answer (score 9):

You can use classical LaTeX (with dvi output) and `dvisvgm` ( http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dvisvgm ) to convert the dvi file to SVG.

EDIT: I am not aware of a *svgtex implementation that does the conversion in one step.

Comment: Could you explain, why going via DVI is an improvement over going via PDF?

Comment: @Jost Frankly, no, but the OP asked for a pdf-free way to achieve his goal.

Comment: Not me but the OP asked the question. I'm just curious.

Comment: i (the "OP", i assume - what does it mean anyway?) elaborated above why i looked for a pdf-free method. i'll certainly try your suggestion using dvi - thanks for that! However, i'm starting to feel that pdflatex is not the real problem, and i'll run into the same trouble with dvi...

Comment: @lukas.coenig OP is our slang for "original poster"

Comment: Also possible: `xelatex --no-pdf`  producing extended DVI (file ending `xdv`) and subsequent conversion to SVG with `dvisvgm`.

Answer (score 3):

In my windows, this works,

Install:

1. [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) (select 64 bit)
2. [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.1/) (select 64 bit)

Then add the "bin" folder to path.

For example, I add "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin" and "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.54.0\bin" to the user path.

If you have a "document.tex" file, then

```
pdflatex document.tex
gswin64 -dNoOutputFonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o tmp.pdf document.pdf
inkscape -o document.svg tmp.pdf
```

Here gswin64 can convert the text to path, avoid the font error when inkscape convert to svg. Although the inkscape has "-T" option that convert text to path, however, this doesn't work sometimes expectially when you are use tikzpicture.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a command line tool to convert mathematical expressions in tex to svg (via pdflatex and pdf2svg): https://github.com/yannikschaelte/tex2svg

Example usage:

```bash
tex2svg '$\exp(i\cdot\pi) + 1 = 0$' out.svg
```

(Disclaimer: I'm the author, so likely biased.)