# Export equation into vector graphic

Tags: equations, export

I want to export equations from LaTeX to PowerPoint (if possible as vector graphic, e.g. `.svg`). I use Windows7 / Office 2010 and ShareLaTeX. Since I would like to export every equation, I tried:

```
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \dot x = f(x(t))
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    x(t_0) = x_0
\end{equation}
```

But I have no idea, how to convert the `.pdf` into a `.svg`-file.

Would be great, if somebody could help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Might http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288065/convert-pdf-to-clean-svg help?

Comment: How about [Convert LaTeX to SVG online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103282/convert-latex-to-svg-online)?